# Awesome Weapons - Challenge #2

Tags: discussion, contest

## Contest: Crazy Firepower

The two most modeled things in blender are shiny cars and awesome guns.
Here we are going to expand a little and make any type of weapon. It can be anything, from a rugged battle axe, to a powerful scy-fi cannon. It can be an existing weapon, or something totally new. It only needs to look cool and be semi realistic

**Objective: Create an artwork whose main subject is an awesome weapon.**

You can use any method you want, as long as you use only Blender, but it must in some way resemble a weapon.

**Rules:**

- Only *new and original* work
- Blender only, non commercial add-ons are allowed
- Keep it nice, nothing you wouldn't want to show to a five year old.
- If any doubt is raised about the validity of your entree, you will be required to Include .blend file, so we can be sure it is yours (use [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com))
- The competition runs for a week, you can edit/change your submission at anytime
- Late entries will be disqualified
- Only one entry per person
- Downvotes will not be considered when picking the winner

**Voting guide:**

<sup>(Going beyond the simple visual appeal)</sup>

1. Meets objective, not missing anything
2. No rules were broken
3. Artistically sound:

   - [Good composition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8i7OKbWmRM)
   - [Good use of color](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qj1FK8n7WgY)
   - Solid [design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design)
4. Well Executed

   - Technically impressive
   - Quality of execution meets artistic goals.
5. It is awesome!!!

**Winning criteria:**
Submission with the **most upvotes** as of December 4<sup>th</sup> 2014. The submission must to be posted before the deadline.

**Deadline: December 1<sup>st</sup> 2014 at UTC +0000**

## And most importantly, have fun!

## Results:

**Winner:**
**[NoviceInDisguise](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/550/3127) [6 votes]**

- [X-27](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/551/3127) [5 votes]
- [David](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/552/3127) [4 votes]

*All other entries were to late to qualify*

Comment: This looks like fun! Good choice!

Comment: @X-27 Does it \*have\* to be some powerful weapon?

Comment: No, it just needs to look like something that could be used as a weapon.

Comment: Is it one vote per voter, or can you upvote several entrees? Upvoting all would, of course, be pointless, but upvoting, say, two out of four, may make a difference in the end.

Comment: Seeing as there is no way to regulate it effectively, I would say vote on as many as you want. Adding restrictive rules that can not be enforced is completely useless.

Comment: @SixthOfFour you can definitely upvote as many entrees as you want.

Comment: @SixthOfFour the only thing up voting all of them would do is essentially lower your entree by one vote, because you can't vote yourself up.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise Good points.

Comment: @David Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: How to submit yeah? i've got my model ready.

Comment: @Vince Scalia You just add an answer with your artwork embedded as an image, a little description, and maybe even a caption. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to the forest! Here is my entry, that I have been working on over the past few days. The characters are fully rigged, everything is UV-unwrapped. I think in this piece I got much of my inspiration from the "crazy" in Crazy Firepower, but I hope you all can understand and appreciate the story behind this piece of art.

Created in Blender 2.72 and Cycles, with advanced compositing in the compositor, and some minor post processing in Paint.NET.

**Tree Cannon - The Oak's Last Stand**

(click for full size)
[image: Tree Cannon]

Description:

> War broke out in the forest, with a new species of tree making it's
>   presence known. A hard, cruel species, hardly even a tree at all. The
>   other citizens of the forest lack the ability to overcome their slow,
>   methodical onslaught. They utilize those they vanquish to create
>   machines of destruction, of terror.

This artwork is dedicated to all of those helping prevent invasive species from spreading.

Comment: Wow ! that is nice! mine is still rendering...

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep my eyes peeled for when yours gets posted, should be good if your past work is any indicator!

Comment: Why did you roll back my edit, then go back to it? I would never change the content of your entree. In the *Edit Summary* I wrote what I changed. I really like the story and message behind your image.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you had changed. I was trying to find the original version for a comparison, and accidentally rolledback your edit. I hope it didn't get you any negative points?

Comment: no problem. No I would not and did not loose anything. You can always look at the edit history by clicking the link at the bottom of any edited post that says "edited X hours ago"

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! And I am glad I didn't mess you up.

Comment: Quick critique: The image could have benefited from some more head room the rightmost oak's eye is too close to the top of the image. You could have either moved the camera up a bit or changed the aspect ratio.

Comment: Good point!Thank you for the input, I'll keep an eye out for mistakes like that in the future.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise When you're ready to post you're image, go through the voting guidelines. I put them their (I wrote the original template) not only to guide the voting, but as a reminder to artists on how to create better images. PD I really like the tone of your image. Good use of design!

Comment: Thanks for the input! I really appreciate it, and it really helps me progress faster!

Answer (score 8):

*X-27 Anti Material Pulse Beam Emitter*

Made in *Blender* using *cycles* render engine.

(click for higher resolution)
[image: my entree]
due to the .jpg artifacts you can't quite make out the caution label. it reads

CAUTION

X-27 ULTRA CANNON

EXTREMELY POWERFUL

DO NOT LOOK INTO BEAM

UNLESS YOU ARE WEARING

THE X-27 FORCEFIELD

Comment: Interesting! A very different approach from mine, I can't see what else will show up over the next few days!

Comment: Did it meet your expectations?

Comment: Pretty much ;-) Maybe work on the wall a little, the tiling of the texture is pretty obvious. Maybe spend the rest of the next few days trying to make it a little more photorealistic?

Comment: I was thinking of adding some barbed wire on top, and maybe some cracks or damage marks on the concrete.

Comment: That would really add a lot to it! Any ideas of ways to improve mine?

Comment: not really, yours is great! the only thing i can think of is using the sunbeams node to make really cool light effects.

Comment: Good idea! I'll see what I can come up with . . .

Comment: Looking better! Doesn't quite match with the environment now, though . . .

Comment: It is early yet in the competition, got plenty of time to get more votes ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19037/discussion-between-noviceindisguise-and-x-27).

Answer (score 4):

My entry for the Awesome Weapons contest.

A military testing zone where work is being done on a rail gun launched intercontinental  missile.
<sub>click for full size</sub>
[image: Awesome Weapon]

Comment: Awesome textures. could use more ammo and more detail.

Comment: Yeah a little bare. you can edit though.

Comment: What would make this scene more interesting is a hole clipped in the fence, and a sign of the weapon having been tampered with. Then it would tell a story. :-)

Comment: @Mentalist thank you for the suggestions. If I ever come back to this piece, I will add more of a story. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Though this contest is called "crazy firepower" there are clear provisions in the rules for any kind of weapon, including melee. So I present to you

**BwadiBwa Kobold Mk. III**

For hi-rez: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OsaM.png

[image: at 150 samples]

This is a knife. I think you can probably see that.
On the back i put my special 'Vince Scalia' symbol; the Kifwebe mask: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfJux.png

(that pic was taken before i was finished btw.)

Generally if you couldn't reach your opponent with a weapon like this you'd just throw it at them, and even if it didn't hit blade first, it still weighs five pounds and would clunk them pretty good.

Comment: Good concept, according to the rules, this does look cool and could certainly be considered a weapon. however you entered after the deadline so sadly this entree does not qualify to win. :-(

Comment: o shucks. i thought it was dec 4

Comment: No, December 4th is the point when the voting ends and the winner is declared. the entrees had to be in by December 1st

Comment: okay, sorry. that's a bummer though. You like the knife?

Comment: Yah, I thought the topic awesome weapons would attract more participants, however this contest had a lower result than the last one....

Comment: Something I guess. Maybe a longer entry period?... just kidding.

Comment: well, there is always next time.

Comment: Heh Heh. yeah. It'll be fun, and I'll make sure I enter early. I did that on my black belt test too.

Comment: I really like that one, and you have my vote even though it won't count. :)

Comment: Thanks.........