# Mechanics - Challenge #3

Tags: discussion, contest

## Contest: Mechanics

3D artists always enjoy rendering impressive, shiny machines, from robots to complex vehicles. But often times they wouldn't work in the real world.

**Objective: Create a machine that is mechanically functional.**

You can use any method you want, as long as you use Blender for all modelling and rendering. Both Blender Internal and Cycles render engines may be used. Minor post processing in 2D photo editing programs is permitted.

**Rules:**

- Only *new and original* work.
- Blender only, non commercial add-ons are allowed.
- Keep it nice, nothing you wouldn't want to show to a five year old.
- If any doubt is raised about the validity of your entry, you will be required to show a .blend file, so we can be sure it is yours (use pasteall.org). Otherwise your entry will be disqualified.
- The competition runs for approximately 3 weeks, you can edit/change your submission at anytime
- Late entries will be disqualified
- Only one entry per person (*Multiple images of the same entry are allowed*)
- Downvotes will not be considered when picking the winner

**Voting guide:**

<sup>(Going beyond the simple visual appeal)</sup>

1. **Mechanically sound:** Would be able to work in the real world.

   - Able to achieve any position that is necessary for it to function
   - Components look sturdy enough to support the weight/strain their function requires
2. Meets objective, not missing anything
3. No rules were broken
4. Artistically sound:

   - Good composition
   - Good use of color
   - Solid design
5. Well Executed

   - Technically impressive
   - Quality of execution meets artistic goals.
6. Judge all included images on all of these points.

**Winning criteria:** 
Submission with the **most upvotes** as of January 9<sup>th</sup> 2015 (UTC +0000). The submission must to be posted before the deadline.

**Competition Ends: January 5<sup>th</sup> 2015 at UTC +0000**

## And most importantly, have fun!

**Winner: [NoivceInDisguise](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/575/3127) [4 votes]**([Again!](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/550/3127))

- [Vince Scalia](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/555/3127)[3 votes]

*If you have any questions, ask them in the [events chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18173/events).*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Golf Ball Machine

---

**Description:**

This machine is an artists rendition of how a golf ball is made. Although all the steps are the same, the way it is achieved is completely different. All parts of this machine are theoretically functional.

**Artwork:**

[image]

**How it works:**
A rubber cube is roughly rounded by a saw, and is then fed into the rotating portion of the machine in the background. The meal cups are electronically heated, and melt the rubber into a spherical shape. A burst of steam is used to loosen the sphere from the mold.

Next the machine on the right is given the sphere, and trims off the edges made during the molding process. The machine then rotates and drops the sphere into the chute, which channels it over to the other side where it is cased and then printed and packaged.

*I only had time to finish part of the machine so far, so more may show up before the 5th.*

Answer (score 3):

### Craig's Hand

Click [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gph81.png) for hirez

[image]

I really could not think of a decent name for this, I apologize.

Here is a small domestic robot who's main duty is that of one of your hands. It measures 1' from foot to finger-tip.

Usefull activities include

- Greeting guests
- Loading printers
- Feeding birds
- Writing
- Typing
- Playing piano

Some *not* so helpful activities (Pre-install, God save us all)

- Doodling on walls
- Rubbing feet on floor, then commencing to 'static shock' people
- Getting fingers stuck in whiffle ball
- Flicking shins

Its joints all consist of a ball and socket, all but the hips and ankles rotate about but one axis. They move using magnetic paddles, akin to a water-wheel. I added some clockwork to the 'birdcage' but it doesn't do anything but tick. All electronics would be housed in the palm.

And, of course, the back of the hand has my [kifwebe mask.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3Bff.png) Comes in two versions, left, or right.

Home delivery; unpacks self.
Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrCby.png) for hirez.

[image]

Comment: You made me laugh so hard! The "some _not_ so helpful activities" part especially :-)

Comment: Laughter is good for the soul :)

Comment: They say laughing can make live longer. If that's true, after seeing this I'll have to be beaten to death at 250 or so. :D

Comment: Well I achieved my goal then.